# Using the 'Performance Mode' on my HP Envy 13t Laptop

Tags: laptop, performance, fan, temperature, hp-envy

I have an HP Envy 13t (2019 edition). My laptop has an Intel i7 chip with 8 GB of RAM. There are settings given in HP Command Center - a Recommended, Performance and Comfort mode. My temps run 50-60 degrees when it is on the Recommended mode (which is mostly the case). The Performance mode only runs on external power. These modes basically control fan speed and so far I have not been able to do it manually without having to install extra software.

The problem is, when I try to run it this way, using the external power adapter almost automatically seems to add 20 degrees. Even if I just run it on Recommended. Is this normal?

How do I try to run it on Performance mode? I assume it would help when I'm running some relatively intense coding tasks, or a game or two in the off-chance.

Comment: Battery charging is an intensive process that generates heat. Once at 100% charge that generated heat should mostly go away but there will still be some generated by the circuitry that takes in the charger voltage and converts it to the internal voltage used by the rest of the laptop.

Comment: I have the same exact setup on an HP Envy 17".  I run it 100% of the time on Performance and have been doing so for years without replacing the power supply.  Not saying yours won't burn up.. just saying that mine hasn't.